# Is grownup, grown up, or grown-up the correct usage (as a noun)?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, compound-words

When used as a noun (meaning an adult), is "grownup", "grown up", or "grown-up" more appropriate?

Comment: Should be **reopened**. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=grownup+or+grown+up+or+grown-up) leads here first. None of the linked sources that I could find (I tried six) answer this question as thoroughly and succinctly as the top-voted [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/154560/18673). Though that answer should be elaborated with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grown-up is the proper noun and adjective form.

Grown up is the past participle of to grow up.

Grownup is a frequently used form, but more dictionaries prefer grown-up.  In fact, if you google *grownup definition* it returns a definition for grown-up.

[One source of many](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-does-grown-need-hyphen)

Answer (score -1):

"Grown up" is something someone has done. It expresses who or what someone is to a rather minimal extent. Now we are left with "grownup" and "grown-up." So now we have to wonder, appropriate for what? "Grown-up" has a certain childish ring to it, you might use it if you are writing from the perspective of a child or childish person. If you are trying to be informal but not immature, "grownup" would probably be best. I personally do not recommend using any form of "grownup" if you are trying to sound like one, or if you are trying to be formal, go for "adult" or another word instead.